# how to solve pack array function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I encountered this question in a coding challenge. There are stack overflow questions on solving similar problem using objects.The twist in this question is to only count the items that are adjacent to each other. It would be great to know a solution for this.

```
pack([5,5,5,7,7,2,4,7]);

output should be [5:3, 7:2, 2:1, 4:1, 7:1]



var dupobject = function(arr){
  var nodup = []; 
  var store = {};
  var prev = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){

     if(arr[i] == prev && store[arr[i]]){
       store[arr[i]] += 1;
       console.log(arr[i]);
     }else{
       store[arr[i]] = 1;
     }

    prev = arr[i];

  }

  console.log(store);
}


dupobject([ 5,5,5,7,7,2,4,7]);
```

Comment: This is a really basic coding question. Have you tried to solve it yourself?

Comment: The output I'm getting is [5:3, 7:1, 2:1, 4:1], don't want 7:2 to be overwritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no one posted answer for it, here we go!

https://plnkr.co/edit/lxKRODtzIfCIgfcKS11F?p=options

```
function aggregate(arr){
  var aggregatedArray = [];

  var consecutiveCount = 1;
  for(var i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
    if(i>0){

      if(arr[i-1] === arr[i] && i !== (arr.length)){
        consecutiveCount++;
      }else{
        var obj = {};
        obj[arr[i-1]] = consecutiveCount;  
        aggregatedArray.push(obj);
        consecutiveCount = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return aggregatedArray;
}
```